# How can I do real-time log analysis using Spark-streaming?? (I attach architecture image)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

Spark streaming application receives data in real time from a lot of IoT devices.
But They are all small amounts of data.
Overall flow looks like it -> Iot -> Kafka(1 topic/ all data) -> Spark-streaming(Filtering error log) -> DB(save) -> Alert screen

Is there a good way to do real-time log analysis using spark or python?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparantly, You can use the spark- Kafka connectors to stream the data from Kafka queue.

This doc has some reference to start with structured streaming with Kafka -  https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html

Once you get the streaming dataframe from kafka,you can apply filter() function from spark to filter your incoming data set.

Also this document from databricks has some nice reference on how we can implement log analysis application using spark streaming.

https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-reference-applications/content/logs_analyzer/app/index.html

You can use above as a reference!

Comment: Thank you, Did that answer clarify your question ?

Comment: @KIMJAEMIN - if it answers your question - can you please accept it as the answer ?

Comment: I do~:) Thanks bro. Can you tell me more "gitbooks site"(?), If you know other "gitbooks"  for spark study

Comment: You can refer to the below link and it has some references for spark apps - https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-reference-applications/content/index.html